# Run-time error '1004' Macro stops running, if workbook with macro isn't the active one

Tags: excel, vba

I use few macros based on Worksheet events and module to make built in timer. If someone didn't make any edition in the file for XX minutes, it will be saved and closed. It works generally but the code breaks from time to time on part `ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden`

I reproduced it few times to locate source of my problem.
It breaks only if that workbook is not as active used. If i work with other workbook and the timer hits XX it breaks my code.

I need those loops to set my sheets to *START Values*.

It is important for my **User Force Macro** to be active. User see only at the beggining **sheet"START"**. If they chose to activate all macros. Sheet START will be hidden and other will be shown.

Module macros:

```
Option Explicit

Dim CloseTime As Date

Sub TimeSetting()
   CloseTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:30")
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
     Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub TimeStop()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
     Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub SavedAndClose()

   Dim ws As Worksheet

   'Step 1: Unhide the Starting Sheet
   Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

   'Step 2: Check each worksheet name
       If ws.Name <> "START" Then
          ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden 'Step 3: Hide the sheet
       End If

   Next ws 'Step 4:  Loop to next worksheet
   ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Workbook macros:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Call TimeStop
   ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
   Next ws

   Sheets("START").Visible = xlVeryHidden
   Call TimeSetting
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Call TimeStop
   Call TimeSetting
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you just need to add `Sheets("START").Select` after you set it visible?

Comment: Sadly that same problem. It doesn't work. I will add rest of my code

Comment: Source of that problem is not selection, but working with other woorkbooks while Timer counts and hits XX. It breaks the code, if that workbook isn't active one

Comment: Check `Application.Ready` before doing anything. Excel in not ready when a cell is being edited.

Comment: Excel is ready, i can't work with other Workbook when timer hits XX. if my Workbook that should be closed is not active one. It breaks code and don't close

Comment: It's Run-time error '1004'

Comment: Supposing you work with another workbook and still want to close then workbook with sheet("start"), then replace `ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True` line with `ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True`. And before hiding make sure sheet("start") is not the last visible sheet in that workbook as you must have at least 1 sheet visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SavedAndClose()

Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Step 1: Unhide the Starting Sheet

On Error GoTo Error
Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
'Sheets("START").Select

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

'Step 2: Check each worksheet name
If ws.Name <> "START" Then

    'Step 3: Hide the sheet
     ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

 'Step 4:  Loop to next worksheet
Next ws

 Error:
 Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
 End Sub
```